# How can I get the name used to open an EventWaitHandle?

Tags: c#, event-wait-handle

I am trying to implement a cross-process event architecture where processes can "subscribe" to events, and then "unsubscribe".

My initial tests using EventWaitHandle are promising (although I've read some negative comments about them, but please set that aside for now).

Since these things are named, and are in fact opened by name using OpenExisting, I was a little surprised to find that the EventWaitHandle class does not have a Name property, so that given a collection of them I can find the one for a given name.

So, given a collection of these things, is there no way to see what name was used to create each one?

Comment: You could save them in a dictionary where the key is the string used when you called the `OpenExisting` method.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  That's actually what I'm doing (exactly what I'm doing... have you been looking at my code??).  But I'm still not sure why this is not something you can get out of the EventWantHandle object.